# How i set TextField height property according to Size wise in Appcelerator Allow?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am new developer with Appcelerator Alloy.
     Plz help me,
     how i set Textfield Height Property according to device Display Size.

in Titanium.

```
  var name_Txt = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        height : (Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight< 481) ? 32 : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight * 6 / 100,
        width : "94%",
        backgroundImage : "../images/textfield_dropdown.png",
        top : "10",
        paddingLeft : "10",
        hintText : "Input Activity - optional scroll",
        font : {
            16,
            fontWeight : "bold",
        },
    });
```

in Alloy

```
<TextField height="?" id="name_Txt" left ="2%" paddingLeft = "5" backgroundImage = "/appimage/textfield.png" width ="60%"></TextField>
```

or in
.tss file

```
"#name_Txt":{
height : ?,
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it programmatically in the controller file for this view. For example,

Say you have a view named main.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <TextField id="name_Txt"></TextField>
</Alloy>
```

A style file named main.tss:

```
"#name_Txt":{
    left : "2%"
    paddingLeft: 5,
    backgroundImage: "/appimage/textfield.png",
    width:"60%"  
}
```

And a controller named main.js:

```
$.name_Txt.height = (Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight< 481) ? 32 : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight * 6 / 100;
```